# display 20 lines only with the_content

Tags: theme-development, theme-twenty-ten

I like to display only 20 lines of post with the read more link using

```
the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ) );
```

But it shows full content .
How can i strip it .please help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a more quicktag to your content

See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Comment: i red it . but couldn't manage to get it. please help me with code.There is lot about changing read more link style but how to strip the content.

Comment: not sure what help you need - just add a more quicktag from the editor to your post. There isn't any code to change

Comment: on sidenote but in keeping with this post, using more tag to limit number of words can overflow if someone comes along and writes from a theosaurus, is there a similar function that can do character count inc whitespace anybody knows of?

Comment: Thank you so much .I have noticed many bad suggestion like using "substr". but i thought there should be a good way. that's You gave

Answer (score 2):

Several options:

1. Manually add the `<!--more-->` link to each of your posts, at the appropriate location (as suggested by @spartacus)
2. Filter `$content` at the `the_content` hook, to return the appropriate amount of content (I'm not sure how you would filter to return *20 lines* of content), plus a read more link
3. Use `the_excerpt()` instead of `the_content()`, and filter `$excerpt` at the `excerpt_length` hook, to return the appropriate number of *words*